# Создание изображения через JS

Tags: javascript

Как в js создавать .png , .jpg  файлы и перерисовывать их, чтобы потом отдавать пользователю? Не хочется на сервере делать.

Нужно создать файл размером, например, 100×100, и нарисовать в нем красный квадрат.

Под перерисовыванием имеется ввиду:

1. загрузить файл
2. записать в него другие данные (например красный квадрат )
3. и отдать пользователю

Comment: как раз такие тяжелые операции на сервере и надо делать. если у вас node.js, то рекомендую библиотеку sharp - весьма дружелюбна в использовании

Comment: что имеется ввиду под перерисовыванием?

Comment: Слишком мало информации в вопросе. Отредактируйте вопрос и распишите более подробно

Comment: В данном случае можно использовать canvas.

Comment: @Grundy можно подробнее?